# "What for" or "What is for"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Which of the following sentences is correct one in the following context?

> "What for?"

or

> "What **is** for?"

Context: 
Someone sent me message and asked me to be a follower on Instagram. What of the above sentences is more accurate to use?

Comment: ***Which*** of the following sentences...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that the phrase *What is for?* is completely ungrammatical. Phonetically, it sounds like you're literally asking what does the word *for* mean:

> What is "for"? *(What does it mean and how to use it?)*

[**What for?**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/what-for) is, of course, the idiom you should use in this situation because it's a legitimate expression in English and it means exactly what you intend to say:

> for what purpose? why?

Example:

> — Tomorrow, I'm going to my Mom's. Will you come with me?
>   — What for?
>   — Well, you could help her in her garden.

Comment: Q: "What is for?" A: "Four is the number that comes after five."

Comment: @J.R. Yes. Phonetically, it can be taken even that far.

Comment: @CookieMonster By putting "for" in quotation marks, you are making the question grammatical, but also likely changing the meaning from what the original poster intended. :)

Comment: If someone was asking verbally instead of writing a question, you'd have no way of knowing which was which. In writing, though, the word being asked about should be in quotation marks or italics; for example: What is _to_?

Comment: How about "what is this for"?

Comment: @Zhang That's what you say when you want to know what something is used for or what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

"What is for?" is not grammatical and shouldn't be used.

Many people colloquially ask "What for?" as a synonym for "Why?", but personally, I think "why" is better - it's shorter and it's clear to everyone, being one of the English language's most commonly-used words.

Comment: As a footnote, even though "What is for?" is indeed an ungrammatical question, the questions "What is ***this*** for?" (or "What is ***that*** for?") are perfect valid, and can be used to mean, "What is the purpose of this?"

Comment: @J.R. That's a fair point.

Comment: Jim M.: What are comments for? ;-)

Comment: @J.R.♦: There's been a fairly long-running [*What are the Welsh for?*](https://www.dailypost.co.uk/news/north-wales-news/radio-ga-ga-2945665) gag in the UK. I can't actually recall seeing ***Why** are the Welsh?*, but syntactically it "sorta" makes sense.